# Open url on an external browser on button click in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt4

My application should contains a button which when you click on it an external browser should be opened 
here is my code

```
void Logindialog::on_inscriptionPushButton_clicked()
{
  QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com", QUrl::TolerantMode));
}
```

but when i compile i get this list of errors

- error: incomplete type 'QUrl' used in nested name specifier
- error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QUrl'
- error: forward declaration of 'class QUrl'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to include QUrl, as only a forward declaration exists.

Use either `#include <QUrl>` or `#include <QtCore>` at the top of your file.